# Window on Scroll Called without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a script for animating content on scroll. But I got triggering this script without having actual scroll. That affects the animation by calling 2 times. And my Block getting opacity from 0 to 1 for 2 times and it looks like its vibrating.

```
.service-item {
    display: block;
    min-height: 175px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0;
    opacity:0;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}


$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if(windowBottom > $('#services').offset().top+100) {
        $('.services .container').addClass("fadeInUp").addClass("animated");
        var delay = 0;
        $('.service-item').each(function(){
            var portfolioImageOffset = $(this).offset().top;
            if(portfolioImageOffset < windowBottom) {
                $(this).delay(delay).animate({
                    opacity:1
                },200);
                delay += 200;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For Output: Go to http://ldrp.890m.com/personal and scroll down to service or our work section.

Comment: For which purpose 'windowBottom' is used ?

Comment: var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
var windowBottom = scrollPos + $(window).height();

windowBottom is used for check if my scroll is reached the top of services div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$('.service-item').each()` function, you could try to add a data-something to check if it has already been animated or not. Like so :

```
$('.service-item').each(function(){
   if($(this).data('animated') != 'animated') {
      var portfolioImageOffset = $(this).offset().top;
      if(portfolioImageOffset < windowBottom) {
         $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            opacity:1
         },200);
         delay += 200;
         $(this).data('animated','animated');
      }
   }
});
```

Tell me if it works! :)

Comment: It Works.. Thanks

Comment: No problem ! I'm glad I could help. :)